# UI is not letting to type query at a normal speed in Google BQ UI portal

Tags: google-bigquery, google-bigquery-dataform

UI is not letting to type query at a normal speed in Google BQ UI portal.
When I start to type a query, its printing very slowly.
My internet speed is good, its problem only with Google BQ UI portal, rest of the internet based applications are working good.

I tried clearing the cache and browsing history.
Apparently these are UI based, not a client a server architecture, apparently I have not much to do on UI side.

I am expecting to let me type a query as fast as I can type a query in notepad or a text pad.